# Docusign ¿Como se debe escribir la función en php para tener un escuchador al cual docusign llama?

Tags: php, symfony2, heroku

Tengo integrado la librería docusign para firmas electrónicas (proyecto en symfony2), en este momento estoy integrando el webhook para que me avise cuando una firma ha cambiado de estado, pero estoy confundido, no sé cómo escribir la función en php la cual va a estar escuchando dicho evento.

Ya seguí todos los pasos de la documentación pero nada aún.

Answer (score 0):

nunca lo he trabajado pero este proyecto pretende crear un listener para Docusign.

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk/tree/master/PHP/Connect

Tomado de:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309848/docusign-custom-connect-how-to-make-a-listener-in-php-example

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español! Te recomiendo veas el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y añadas la información relevante de esos links a tu respuesta ya que los links pueden dejar de ser válidos.